How do I avoid inserting parent on conflict/failure of child inserts?
My tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User
(
    userid VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserType
(
    email       VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    userId      VARCHAR(255),
    type        VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES User (userId)
);

I generate UserId from code and insert using sqlx SQLite:
async fn create_user(
        &self,
        user: &User,
    ) -> Result<(), CreateError> {
        let query = "insert into User (id) values (?1)";
        let query_local = "insert or ignore into UserType (email,user_id) values (?1,?2)";
        let mut conn = self
            .pool
            .acquire()
            .map_err("xxx")
            .await?;

        let mut tx = conn.begin().map_err("xxx").await?;

        sqlx::query(query)
            .bind(user.userid.as_str())
            .execute(&mut *tx)
            .map_err("xxx")
            .await?;
        sqlx::query(query_local)
            .bind(user.email.as_str())
            .bind(user.userid.as_str())
            .execute(&mut *tx)
            .map_err("xxx")
            .await?;
        tx.commit().map_err("xxx").await?;
        Ok(())
    }

In case of a duplicate email from an insert into UserType table, how can I avoid the corresponding UserId getting inserted into the User table (by query or transaction)?

you need a constraint in UserType

also see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Most likely what you actually want here is a transaction https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html then you can ROLLBACK to undo all changes made since the BEGIN.

You'd want to update the query for that by using ON CONFLICT {DO SOMETHING}. It's up to you what that does on a conflict. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html
